# Extracting class usage from within Java methods using ctags

Tags: java, ctags, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to know if it is possible to use `ctags` to extract class usage from within Java methods.  So far, I was able to only use it to get a listing of methods and instance variables but not which classes are utilized within methods.

E.g.

```
...
public void doSomething(MyClass myClassInst) {
     int someVar = myClassInst.getSomeVar();
     System.out.println("Some var is " + someVar);
}
...
```

Right now all I get is a recognition of the method declaration.  But I would like to extract that `doSomething` is also utilizing the classes `MyClass` and `System` but not just to parse the text but also know the full class address including the package (`java.lang.System` and `com.mypackage.MyClass`).

In order to be able to extract this kind of metadata, ctags would need to have access to the  compiler's `abstract syntax tree` and I am not sure if it does that or it simply does text parsing of the source code.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do using ctags or does it eclipse the scope of its functionality?

Comment: How important is it to use ctags?  You can accomplish some code analysis tasks by extending a static analysis tool such as PMD.  PMD should provide an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: not important.  my goal is static code analysis

Comment: In that case, I recommend checking out PMD.  It was not created specifically for your use case, but it should give you the capability you need.

Comment: i installed it and trying to figure out how to get out of it what i need.

Comment: @Los, do you have any idea which command line options to use to accomplish what i am looking for ?

Comment: it is not very well documented

Comment: You will need to write a custom rule to do exactly what you need.  Documentation is here: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/howtowritearule.html .  It uses the visitor pattern.  That page includes the command line usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) or [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) to achieve this.